# Qualtrics: Javascript to prevent saving entry from Text Box

Tags: javascript, textbox, saving-data, qualtrics

I have one Text Box (also called "Text Entry") in my qualtrics survey in which I want participants to write something but I do not want to have the result saved in my data. I do not want to use the password function, therefore I have used JavaScript at the Text Box level.

The code below works to the extent that whatever participants put in the Text Box it will be set to an empty string the moment they hit the Next-Button.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
var currentQuestionID = this.getQuestionInfo().QuestionID

var input = $("QR~"+currentQuestionID);


$('NextButton').onclick = function (event) {
     input.value = ""
}
});
```

**The problem:** This code only works sometimes. For example when I have two textboxes with the exact same code it only works for the first but not the second one. Similarly for some reason if the textbox is embedded in some other questions it doesn't work either.

Does anybody know how I can make this work either by changing my code or with a completely different solution? Essentially, I just want participants to entry some text which will never be saved in my data and I cannot use the password function.

**Solution:** One way of solving this would be adding a "Descriptive Text" item in which you can add some simple HTML code:

```
<p>Please provide your email address:</p><p><br></p>

 <input name="nothing" type="textarea">
```

Comment: Use a class for all the inputs you don't want to save, then set the class' elements to empty? `$(".class").val("");`.

Comment: Please tell us why it is good idea to waste respondents' time typing text that you are going to immediately throw out.

Comment: @Henry A.: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I don't know enough about JavaScript to put your suggestion into action without further hints. Nonetheless, a colleague suggestion a solution that works (see above).

Comment: @T. Gibbons: Thank you for taking the time to write such a helpful response. In research we sometimes pretend we are interested in some confidential information from participants, for example, if we want to see whether they sign up for a fake advertising/project. Nonetheless, for ethical reasons the confidential information must not be saved.

Comment: Thank you for the sarcasm. It was a comment for clarification, not a response.  Also, thank you for confirming that you are intentionally misleading respondents.  I do lots of research, but not that kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think JavaScript works well in this case as it can't be guaranteed to run before the page has sent the data.

The best way is to make a dummy HTML "question" which has the appearance of a form but does not save any information.

I tried this out in a test survey by adding a question of type "Descriptive Text", and then in "HTML View" for that question, adding:

```
<p>This is not a real question, there is just a HTML textarea. </p>
<form id="mydummyform">
<input name="nothing" type="textarea" />
</form>
```

I found that this sometimes showed the HTML source instead of the form in the survey editor; if it does this, just go to "HTML View" and then "Normal View" and it should resolve correctly. This problem was only in the editor -- it always showed correctly in a preview of the survey.